# Using oblique coordinates in SVG

Tags: svg, coordinate-systems

[This Code Golf SE question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/258642/76093) gives coordinates in a 60 degree oblique coordinate system. While it's perfectly possible to convert those coordinates to orthonormal, I'm curious if there's a way to globally force e.g. `<path>` elements to calculate in oblique coords.

For example, here's my current code:

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <symbol id="swoop">
                <path d="m 5 1 c 1 2 2 6 -5 14 l 5 -3 c 4 -6 3 -10 1 -12 l -1 1"/> 
        </symbol>
    </defs>
<g transform="matrix(1.11535507165,-0.29885849072,-0.29885849072,1.11535507165,-2,3)translate(400,500)scale(20)">
<!--Note: Due to svg weirdness I had to manually transform #swoop's path. That's why this translate is here.-->
<use href="#swoop" fill="#5A318E" transform="translate(2,-3)"/>
<use href="#swoop" fill="#5A318E" transform="translate(2,-3)rotate(60,0,0)"/>
<use href="#swoop" fill="#5A318E" transform="translate(2,-3)rotate(120,0,0)"/>
<use href="#swoop" fill="#5A318E" transform="translate(2,-3)rotate(180,0,0)"/>
<use href="#swoop" fill="#5A318E" transform="translate(2,-3)rotate(240,0,0)"/>
<use href="#swoop" fill="#5A318E" transform="translate(2,-3)rotate(300,0,0)"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

which produces this:

[image]

Evidently doing basis transforms in `<g>` doesn't work as I'm expecting it to.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, I would submit an answer in Code Golf myself, but since it is a legitimate question for SO, here is an answer *in principle*, leaving out the golfing which would be considered bad practice around here.

The key transformation is `skewX(30) scale(1 0.866)`, which shortens the Y values and then [tilts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/skewX) the Y axis 30 degrees clockwise, leaving the length effectively unchanged. Note that in SVG the Y axis points *down*. This means for the intended result there has to be a third transform `scale(1 -1)`.

The hexagon on top cannot be written as skewed, because the stroke would also be skewed, resulting in an unequal stroke width.

```html
<svg viewBox="-14 -12 28 24" >
  <defs>
    <path id="swoosh" d="M3-2C4,0 5,4-2,12L3,9C7,3 6-1 4-3Z" transform="scale(1-1)skewX(30)scale(1 0.866)" />
  </defs>
  <g id="third">
    <use href="#swoosh" fill="#5A318E" />
    <use href="#swoosh" transform="rotate(60)" fill="#54A2E1" />
  </g>
  <use href="#third" transform="rotate(120)" />
  <use href="#third" transform="rotate(240)" />
  <path d="M-2,5.2 3.5,4.33 5.5-0.87 2-5.2-3.5-4.33-5.5,0.87Z" style="fill:none;stroke:#576AB7;stroke-width:.5" />
</svg>
```